# Problemas com lentidão SQL LINQ C# Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Estou utilizando Entity frameWork, tenho uma lista de objetos (dados retirados do banco) com dados de Clientes,

```
public virtual DbSet<clientes> clientes {get;set;}


public IEnumerable<clientes> FindAll()
{   db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    return db.clientes.ToList();
}
```

e depois no meu form, tenho um Grid

```
grid.datasource = clientes.ToList();
```

estou chamando a lista logo no 'On Load' do form, estou apenas com 3 registro na base de dados (SQLSERVER) e está demorando mais de 10 segundos para abrir o form..

Na classe mapeada a PK está desta forma :

```
[Key]
public int pk_cliente {get;set;}
```

Estava pensando se o mapeamento da PK está errada e ele está se perdendo em alguma parte.

Comment: [Já tentou perfilar seu sistema antes?](http://miniprofiler.com) Não acho que seja o Entity Framework o motivo da lentidão, pelo que disse.

Comment: Em vez de mandar dar um return direto no .ToList() você cria uma variavel e joga o tolist nela, no momento do tolist ele vai no banco e volta. O tempo de executar essa linha será o tempo gasto com o banco de dados. Tenta isso e fala o resultado.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @Renan sim, consegui! Já postei a resposta, obrigado por perguntar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pela sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99757/2999), o problema de lentidão vem da carga preguiçosa, que possivelmente é feita para um resultado grande. Vai ficar lento mesmo.

A função abaixo lembra um repositório, que é **uma abordagem muito errada de usar** com Entity Framework, que já implementa um repositório. De qualquer forma, a antecipação de carga (ou simplesmente, usar `JOIN` para o caso de bancos de dados relacionais) pode ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
public IEnumerable<modelos> FindBy(string valor)
{
       return db.modelos
                 .Include(m => m.Peca)
                 .Include(m => m.Produto)
                 .AsEnumerable();
}
```

`valor` não é nem usado, mas mantive apenas a título de exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Estava utilizando o contexto para fazer todas as pesquisas, então quando dava o comando db.clientes.ToList(), dentro da minha classe contexto tenho outros modelos, então ele passava um por um (criando o mapeamento), então eu crie uma query para cada evento, assim não deixo o entity montar o select para mim, eu mesmo faço da seguinte forma :

```
    private Context db = new Context();
    private IQueryable query;   


 public IEnumerable<modelos> FindBy(string valor)
    {
           query = from m in db.modelos
                   join p in db.pecas on m.fk_Peca equals p.pk_Peca
                   join po in db.produtos on m.fk_Produto equals  po.pk_Produto
                   select new { m,p,po};

        return query as IEnumerable<modelos>;
    }
```

Passando para o GridView :

```
gridViewDetalhes.DataSource = _Modelos.FindBy(edtCodigoModelo.Text).ToList();
```

Ajudou muito no meu caso, entretanto estou trabalhando neste projeto com um amigo, utilizando o mesmo tipo de notbook e mesma versão de visual stuido (Community 2015) e quando ele efetuava a abertura do form, não demorava.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Não é bem este o problema. Você resolveu antecipando a carga. Vou escrever uma resposta que dá uma abordagem um pouco mais atual ao seu problema.